# Docker-compose environment variables

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to setup a postgres container and want to setup the postgres login with:

```
POSTGRES_USER: docker
POSTGRES_PASSWORD: docker
```

So I have created the docker-compose.yml like so

```
web:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "62576:62576"
  links:
   - redis
   - db
db:
  image: postgres
  environment:
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: docker
    POSTGRES_USER: docker

redis:
   image: redis
```

I have also tried the other syntax for environment variable declaring the db section as:

```
db:
  image: postgres
  environment:
   - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker
   - POSTGRES_USER=docker
```

However neither of these options seem to work because for whatever reason whenever I try to connect to the postgres database using the various connection strings:

```
postgres://postgres:postgres@db:5432/users
postgres://postgres:docker@db:5432/users
postgres://docker:docker@db:5432/users
```

They all give me auth failures as opposed to complaining there is no users  database.

Comment: `@db` implies a remote connection and nothing suggests you've allowed them in `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf`, especially the last one. It doesn't make sense to not include directly the auth error message in this question.

Comment: I am experiencing a very similar problem. I have done the necessary changes in `pg_hba.conf` to allow remote connections. The problem seems to be `docker-compose` being ignoring the environment variable `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`

Answer (score 101, accepted):

I struggled with this for a while and wasn't having luck with the accepted answer, I finally got it to work by removing the container:

```
docker-compose rm postgres
```

And then the **volume** as well:

```
docker volume rm myapp_postgres
```

Then when I did a fresh `docker-compose up` I saw `CREATE ROLE` fly by, which I'm *assuming* is what was missed on the initial `up`.

---

The reasons for this are elaborated on [here](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/41#issuecomment-167603905), on the Git repo for the Docker official image for postgres.

Comment: does that mean the environment variables are only read on the first run and are ignored on all later runs? If so, it would probably be better to leave out those variables and those values manually after the first run

Comment: Yes @wotanii it appears that is the reason. Your insight led me to [this corresponding issue](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/41#issuecomment-167603905). I'll update answer to reference it too. Thanks!

Comment: Can confirm that if you're encountering this issue when deploying on a swarm with VOLUMES, it is very important that you also reset the volume.

Comment: wow, thank you very much @dukedave. You made my day with your answer!

Comment: spent over a day on this before finding this answer.  Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me as well, for some reason I got the no "postgres" role...wrong password as well...With the first command you posted worked. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me too. I already has postgres container before with different env variables (user,pass, and db). For me, I only need to remove the volumes. First I run `docker volumes ls`. After find the right name for postgres volume, I run `docker volumes rm <volume name>`, then simply `docker-compose up -d --build --force-recreate` did for me.

Comment: I removed the images with `docker-compose down`, removed the original images in the docker GUI, but only your answer has helped me...

Comment: I wasted so many hours of my life just for `docker-compose rm` to solve it.... it's like Drupal clear cache, twice...

Comment: My 2 cents here: `docker-compose down -v`. That was enough for me to get up and running again on a W10 WSL2 machine with `postgres:13-alpine`.

Comment: This turned out to be exactly my problem, so glad i found this answer thanks very much!
Watch your volumes on a growing docker-compose, turns out i had multiple postgres containers all using the same docker volume, derp.

Comment: Mate, you have saved my day here. Years later this gift keeps on giving. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 49):

If you're using **Docker**.

Try to check if your local DB is active because mostly it's conflicting with Docker, if so, you can deactivate it or change port number or uninstall it in order to avoid the conflict.

Comment: Jesus, I've had 3 engineers at this for the last full day trying to figure out what the problem was. Then someone pointed out this comment. Turned out someone had installed local postgres ages ago to test it out and we were trying to connect to the wrong postgres -_-. Killed the windows service, now works like a charm. THANK YOU!

Comment: Very glad to hear that this helped

Comment: @FatalCatharsis I feel you 
Thanks Abdel

Comment: I wasted a whole day until I saw this. Thanks a lot. wish I could upvote twice

Comment: I guess Docker logs not showing any failed login attempt should have rang a bell. I've exposed a different port and can have both instances running concurrently - thank you!

Comment: Haha, wasted a whole day before I saw this. Now I just changed the port of my postgres docker image - worked like a charm !

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. Saved me a lot of pain

Comment: Also had this issue. Thank you that you are pointed it out!

Answer (score 24):

The authentication error you got would help a lot!

I fired up the postgres image with your arguments:

```
docker run --name db -d -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker -e POSTGRES_USER=docker postgres
```

Then I exec'ed in :

```
docker exec -it db psql -U docker user
psql: FATAL:  database "user" does not exist
```

I get the error message you are expecting because I have trust authentication :

```
docker exec -it db cat /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf | grep -v '^#'

local   all             all                                     trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

To simulate your web container, I'll run another instance of the postgres container and link the db container and then connect back to the db container:

```
core@ku1 /tmp/i $ docker run --rm --name web --link db:db -it postgres psql -h db -Udocker user
Password for user docker: 
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "docker"
```

I get an authentication error if I enter the incorrect password.  But, if I enter the correct password:

```
core@ku1 /tmp/i $ docker run --rm --name web --link db:db -it postgres psql -h db -Udocker user
Password for user docker: 
psql: FATAL:  database "user" does not exist
```

It all seems to be working correctly.  I put it all in a yaml file and tested it that way as well:

```
web:
  image: postgres
  command: sleep 999
  ports:
    - "62576:62576"
  links:
   - db
db:
  image: postgres
  environment:
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: docker
    POSTGRES_USER: docker
```

then fired it up with docker-compose:

```
core@ku1 /tmp/i $ docker-compose -f dc.yaml up
Creating i_db_1...
Creating i_web_1...
Attaching to i_db_1, i_web_1
db_1  | ok
db_1  | creating template1 database in /var/lib/postgresql/data/base/1 ... ok
db_1  | initializing pg_authid ... ok
db_1  | initializing dependencies ... ok
db_1  | creating system views ... ok
db_1  | loading system objects' descriptions ... ok
db_1  | creating collations ... ok
db_1  | creating conversions ... ok
db_1  | creating dictionaries ... ok
db_1  | setting privileges on built-in objects ... ok
db_1  | creating information schema ... ok
db_1  | loading PL/pgSQL server-side language ... ok
db_1  | vacuuming database template1 ... ok
db_1  | copying template1 to template0 ... ok
db_1  | copying template1 to postgres ... ok
db_1  | syncing data to disk ... ok
db_1  | 
db_1  | WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
db_1  | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
db_1  | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
db_1  | 
db_1  | Success. You can now start the database server using:
db_1  | 
db_1  |     postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/data
db_1  | or
db_1  |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
db_1  | 
db_1  | 
db_1  | PostgreSQL stand-alone backend 9.4.1
db_1  | backend> statement: CREATE DATABASE "docker" ;
db_1  | 
db_1  | backend> 
db_1  | 
db_1  | PostgreSQL stand-alone backend 9.4.1
db_1  | backend> statement: CREATE USER "docker" WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'docker' ;
db_1  | 
db_1  | backend> 
db_1  | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2015-04-12 22:01:12 UTC
db_1  | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1  | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 docker-compose -f dc.yaml up
core@ku1 /tmp/i $ bg
```

you can see that the user and password were created. I exec in:

```
core@ku1 /tmp/i $ docker exec -it i_web_1 psql -Udocker -h db user
Password for user docker: 
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "docker"
core@ku1 /tmp/i $
db_1  | FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "docker"
db_1  | DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5"

core@ku1 /tmp/i $ docker exec -it i_web_1 psql -Udocker -h db user
Password for user docker: 
psql: FATAL:  database "user" does not exist
db_1  | FATAL:  database "user" does not exist
```

So the only thing I can think of is that you are trying to connect to the database from your host, not the web container?  Or your web container is not using the 'db' as the host to connect to?  Your definition for the web container does not contain any errors that I can see.

Comment: Thanks for your help, turns out something odd happened when creating the image for the first time causing the authentication issues that I saw. Executing a `docker-compose rm` and then `docker-compose up` fixed it

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem, and in my case problem was fixed with a single command:

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate
```

Comment: I tried this option, but afterwards I get this error: Error response from daemon: Duplicate mount point: /var/lib/postgresql/data

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to Bryan with the `docker-compose exec containername env` I have discovered that the need is also to delete volumes. Since for the `docker-compose volume rm volumename` you need to know the exact name it is easier just to delete all with:

```
docker-compose down --volumes
```

Answer (score 7):

This helped me

```sh
docker stop $(docker ps -qa) && docker system prune -af --volumes && docker compose up
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, running `postgres:13-alpine` in a windows 10 `WSL2`, none of the above solutions did the trick.

My mistake was that the docker `network` name I was using was shared with another project. Let's say I have projects A and B, both with the following structure:

```
myappfolder
  - docker-compose.yml
    - services
        - app
            - depends on db
        - db
```

It happens that, by default, `docker-compose` takes the `network` name from the parent directory name of the `docker-compose.yml` file. Therefore both projects, A and B were trying to connect to the same network: `myappfolder_default`.

To solve this:

1. ensure network names are unique among projects:

   a. either change the name of the root folder to be unique

   b. or edit you `docker-compose.yml` to set an explicit network name
2. do `docker-compose down -v` **this will reset all the possible dbs you had defined in your network > make sure you make a psql dump before proceeding**
3. do `docker-compose up`

More networking docs here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: Esto funciona para mi , gracias

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation. Following the answer from @Greg, I did a **docker-compose up**, and it picked up the environment variable.

Prior to that, I had just been using **docker-compose run** and it wasn't picking up the environment variable as proven by running **docker-compose exec task env**. Strangely, **docker-compose run task env** showed the environment variable I was expecting.