# Usage of env variable in docker compose run command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Running the command `docker-compose run -e TYPE=result mongo_db_backup` should give me the value of the given TYPE variable:

```
mongo_db_backup:
  image: 'mongo:3.4'
  volumes:
    - '/backup:/backup'
  command: sh -c '$$(echo $TYPE)'
```

But instead I get the error `The TYPE variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.` What am I doing wrong

Comment: Try `sh -c "echo $TYPE"`

Comment: I'm getting the same error and a blank like. I don't understand why TYPE is empty as it is set in the command...

Comment: Can you change command to `env | grep TYPE=` and reply with what gets printed to the console?

Comment: `TYPE=result` is my output for that... as expected...

Comment: try to use {} for env variable `command: sh -c '$$(echo ${TYPE})'`

Comment: @BukharovSergey This results in the `TYPE variable is not set` error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It happens that Compose expands `$TYPE` before it gets to the inside of the container. Compose looks for the `$TYPE` environment variable in the shell or host environment and substitutes its value in.

This will work with the following terminal command:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
command: sh -c 'echo $TYPE'
```

**terminal command**

```
TYPE='hello world' docker-compose run web
```

When there is no `$TYPE` environment variable in the host machine, Compose sets the value of `$TYPE` to an empty string and outputs a warning.

Compose needs to be informed not to expand `$TYPE` since we want it expanded inside of the shell running in the container.

For this use

**docker-compose.yml**

```
command: sh -c "echo $$TYPE"
```

> Prepending a dollar symbol to `$TYPE` escapes it.

#### Reference:

- [Variable Substitution in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution)