# Docker-compose double dollar sign: can I reference an environment variable from within?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to avoid docker-compose environment interpolation, but I want the entrypoint to reference the environment variables I am passing to the container.

Take this service:

```
whatever:
    image: whatever
    entrypoint: echo "$$MNEMONIC"
    env_file:
      - etc/env_whatever
```

In my etc/env_whatever, I have an environment variable defined as MNEMONIC=blablabla

When I run the service, what I get is this, literally: `$MNEMONIC`. I want to print the actual MNEMONIC value that is passed through the env_file, so I should be getting `blablabla`.

I am struggling with this because all the searches I get are related to just scaping the dollar sign and other issues. I guess I could workaround this by making a customized Dockerfile, but I am trying to avoid that too. Am I asking an impossible?

Comment: Hello, try to create `.env` files at the same level as your `docker-compose.yml`. Put there content of `env_whatever` without dollars. And check if it works - https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#configure-compose-using-environment-variables#the-env-file

Comment: Hi @404pio ! Thank you for your reply. To my knowledge that would be equivalent to using the environment interpolation / substitution, which I am trying to avoid: docker-compose would be taking the envs from the host and then substituting the value directly in the entrypoint. If I don't find any other solution, I will be taking this approach anyway :)

Comment: Hello once again - check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40447029/docker-compose-environment-variable-for-command

Comment: Hi again @404pio , that 's exactly what I have tried with no result. I have the same problem as described in one comment of the solution: `This doesn't work for me. When I used $${VAR_NAME}, the value when echo that var is $VAR_NAME – Minh Danh Aug 24 '18 at 4:53`