# Using internal container environment variables in docker-compose.yml under command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

#### Problem

I'm trying to get the command inside the docker-compose.yml to use the internal environment variables of the container, rather than the ones of the host system. However, docker compose tries to substitute environment variables in the command with the ones of my own shell, outside the container.

E.g. with the following compose-file:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  service1:
    image: alpine
    command: "echo $PATH"
    network_mode: bridge
```

The output contains the PATH of my own shell, not the one inside the container (The variable is getting substituted by Docker).

#### What I've tried

Using a double dollar character as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40472001/7690374). This gives me the following behavior:

| YAML syntax | Console Output |
| --- | --- |
| `command: "echo ${PATH}"` | (Still my own shell PATH variable) |
| `command: "echo $$PATH"` | `$PATH` |
| `command: "echo $${PATH}"` | `${PATH}` |

As noted above I want the console output to read the value of the actual PATH variable in the container (For the alpine container, the output should be `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`)

I've also tried `command: "printenv"`, which as expected shows the above internal value of the PATH variable, and not the one from my shell.

**Update1**
I've also tried the exec format as proposed in the comments, with the following forms:

- `command: ["echo", "${PATH}"]`
- `command: ["echo", "$$PATH"]`
- `command: ["echo", "$${PATH}"]`
  These still give the same results as above.

#### Additional Context

OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Compose version: v2.12.2

#### Question

How can I use internal environment variables inside the command, so that the output of my command will give me the value of the internal PATH variable?

Comment: `command` can have the shell format (what you are using) or exec form (recommended). Maybe that is what going on. Take a look here 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

Comment: @JoaoVitorino Thanks for your comment! I've tried the exec form also, but it gives the same results (See update above). Note that I've edited my example to using the $PATH variable, to make it more clear that I would want to use internal container environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Compose documentation on variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution) notes that `$VARIABLE` references will be replaced with the corresponding *host* environment variable anywhere in the `docker-compose.yml` file, including in `command:`.

Accessing a *container* environment variable can be slightly trickier, especially since an entrypoint wrapper script can modify the container environment at startup time.  You need to arrange two things to happen:

1. You need to pass the literal string `echo $PATH`, including the dollar sign, into the container; and
2. You need to make sure a shell runs to process that string.

Unlike in a Dockerfile, Compose will not wrap a plain-string `command:` in `/bin/sh -c`, so you have to provide this yourself.  Either of these forms will work:

```yaml
command: sh -c 'echo $$PATH'
```

```yaml
command:
  - sh
  - -c
  - echo $$PATH
```

But especially notice the double `$$` to force a literal `$` to be passed into the container.

(This construct also assumes the image will run the `command:` as a normal command.  Some images are constructed to ignore `command:` or to force them to be run with a specific interpreter, and you'll get an obscure error trying to run this.)

Comment: Thanks David! This indeed seems to be the only way to do this in a compose file currently. I've accepted the answer. I'm a bit disappointed by docker-compose though, that there's not a more simpler way to do this...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a .env file next to your docker-compose.yaml and place this inside:

`export ENV_VAR=TESTTEST`

There are several other techniques: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using a .env file still causes the variables to be substituted when the compose-file is parsed, rather then when the command is used. As you indicate, this will work for my original example, if I just want to be able to set the value of one of the variables manually, but I'm looking (more in general) at a method to use internal container environment variables inside the command. I've updated my example to use the $PATH variable, to make this more clear.

Comment: `a method to use internal container environment variables inside the command.` I think that is simply not possible. Can you describe your exact use case (in your question) what you want to achieve?

Comment: Looking further in the docs it is clearly stated: "Your configuration options can contain environment variables. Compose uses the variable values from the shell environment in which docker-compose is run. ".

Comment: thanks for your reply! Indeed nearly all variables used inside a docker-compose file are substituted using the variables in the shell environment. However, there seems to be a workaround to still be able to use internal environment variables, as illustrated in the answer above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/74465405/7690374). I've accepted that one, since there indeed doesn't seem to be a more straightforward/better looking method to use internal environment variables in the compose file...

Comment: True, should have read the docs further 2 lines, where it says: `You can use a $$ (double-dollar sign) when your configuration needs a literal dollar sign. This also prevents Compose from interpolating a value, so a $$ allows you to refer to environment variables that you don’t want processed by Compose.` :) Still it would be good to know what your use case really is because this is such a niche or I would even say hacky thing so there must be a more standard way to solve your actual problem.

Comment: Yes @zsolt, you are correct. For my original use, where I set the variable already inside the docker-compose, there was no  real added value, since I can just use variable substitution. However, imagine using a Docker image that includes environment variables (Set using `ENV var=value` inside the original docker file), such as the location of a configuration directory. If you want to run a command on a file in this directory, it would be good to be able to reference the directory in your command using the variable. I do agree though, for most purposes it's not the best way to go...

Comment: I still don't get why you need to this. What you are doing is an unnecessary extra step, that just complicates things (follow [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle): you put a variable inside the container and run the CMD with that variable but you could just add the CMD the command with a variable expanded on the host.