# Are the environment variables available in the command of the service?

Tags: docker-compose

When you declare environment variables in the "environment" block of a docker-compose, are they available in the command of the service?

For example in the following docker-compose $VAR1 seems to not be available, but $HOME is.

```
version: '3.7'
    services:
      appserver:
        image: ****
        command: echo $VAR1 && echo $HOME
        environment:
          - VAR1=XXXX
```

Is there a way to define environment variables in a service to be available in its command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in [docker compose environment variable for command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40447029/docker-compose-environment-variable-for-command?rq=1) the solutions seems to be use this format to access the variable:

```
$${VAR1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables declared in the environment block of a Docker Compose file are available in the command of the service. In the example you provided, the $VAR1 variable is not available because the echo command is being executed by the shell within the container, not by the Dockerfile itself. The $HOME variable is available because it is a predefined environment variable that Docker sets for all containers.

Comment: The command is not supposed to be executed by the shell within the container? Is there another way to be executed? What I need is to has access from there to variable environments defined in the service itself.

Comment: The `$VAR1` variable is for sure available in the shell in the container, if that was not the case, the `environment` clause in the compose file would be useless.

Comment: You can source the file using the following command:
source .env
Once you have sourced the environment file, you will be able to print the value of the $VAR1 variable using the following command:

echo $VAR1
I hope this helps!